# Deactivate ibidtracker in footnotes only (authoryear-icomp style)

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

Is there any possiblity in biblatex to deactivate the `ibidtracker`in footnotes only? I'm quite new to biblatex and have found no solution for this problem yet.

I'm using biblatex with the `authoryear-icomp` citestyle so my quotes usually are in the main text [example: TEXTTEXT (Elden 1998: 73) TEXTTEXT (Ibid.: 28)]. But I also have footnotes (I'm using the command \footnote) to add additional information and quotes. This currently looks like this: "FOOTNOTETEXTFOOTNOTETEXT (Ibid.: 39)" but I would like to have "FOOTNOTETEXTFOOTNOTETEXT (Elden 1998: 39)".

So would like the ibidtracker to work only for the quotes in the main text but not in the footnotes.

Many thanks for your time and any help!

My current settings:

```
\documentclass [paper=a4, DIV10, fontsize=11pt, headsepline, headings=small, bibliography=totoc, numbers=endperiod] {scrreprt}

\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[autostyle,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[obeyspaces]{url}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{table}{chapter}

\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm,includeheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}
\onehalfspacing

\addtokomafont{partentry}{\centering}
\setkomafont{partentrypagenumber}{\color{white}}

\deffootnote{1em}{1em}{\textsuperscript{\thefootnotemark\ }}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithout{footnote}{chapter}

\usepackage{epigraph}
\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.5\textwidth}
\setlength{\epigraphrule}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\textflush}{flushepinormal}

\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\setlength{\headsep}{12mm}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, maxnames=2, sorting=nyt, backend=biber, dashed=false, isbn=false, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

Answer (score 3):

By default the ibidtracker is already keeping separate track of citations in text and in footnotes.  If you just want it to keep track of those in text, then you can modify the coding set-up of `biblatex` to define a new `ibidtracker` option `textonly`:

Text:

[image: Sample text part]

Footnotes:

[image: Sample footnotes]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@textonly{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@textonly
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@textonly
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@textonly
  \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@textonly{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\@secondoftwo}
       {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@textonly{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidreset@textonly{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}

\makeatother

\usepackage[style=authoryear, citestyle=authoryear-icomp, maxnames=2,
sorting=nyt, backend=biber, dashed=false, isbn=false,
uniquename=false,ibidtracker=textonly]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Article{Elden,
  author =   {Elden, A.},
  title =    {Something},
  journal =  {S. Jor.},
  year =     1998
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\cite[73]{Elden} and \cite[28]{Elden} but\footcite[52]{Elden} or
\footcite[71]{Elden} or even\footnote{\cite[20]{Elden}}.
\end{document}
```

The above coding is based on that for the `context` ibidtracker in `biblatex2.sty`, but when the footnote test is true, we do as little as possible.