# ibidem only in the footnotes and not in the running text

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

Is there a way to have the ibidem-funtion of `biblatex` *only* in the footnotes (`\footcite{key}` and `\footnote{\cite{key}.}`) *but not* in the running text (`bla bla \cite{key} bla bla`)?

In other words, I like the behaviour in the footnotes, but I don't want to read `ibidem` in the running text (or generally in anything other than a footnote).

(Surely if `\autocite` is able to determine by itself whether it is issued in a footnote (thus expanding to `\cite`) or in the running text (thus expanding to `\footcite`), there must be a way to make the idemtracker context-dependent as well, right?

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backend=biber]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the first right page \cite{A01}. That is ok.

\clearpage

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the left page \cite{A01}. That is ok.

\clearpage

Now some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the right page \cite{A01}. That is not ok.

Again, some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the right page \cite{A01}. That is not ok.

\clearpage

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the left page \cite{A01}. That is ok.

Again, some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the left page \cite{A01}. That is not ok.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert this code before loading `biblatex`

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@foot
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@foot
  \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidreset@foot{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
    {}
\makeatother
```

and add the option `ibidtracker=foot` when loading `biblatex`.

MWE:

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrbook}

\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@foot
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@foot
  \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidreset@foot{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
    {}
\makeatother

\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backend=biber,ibidtracker=foot]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the first right page \cite{A01}. That is ok.

\clearpage

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the left page \cite{A01}. That is ok.

\clearpage

Now some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the right page \cite{A01}. That is not ok.

Again, some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the right page \cite{A01}. That is not ok.

\clearpage

Some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the left page \cite{A01}. That is ok.

Again, some text with a footnote.\footcite[99]{A01}

And now a reference in the text on the left page \cite{A01}. That is not ok.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

P.S. The idea is taken from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/179281/27635) of Andrew Swann, but does the opposite.