# Diffrent ibidtracker for text and foot - Problem with footcites (Biblatex)

Tags: biblatex

I needed to deactivate the ibidtracker in text to prevent the "ibid" by 2nd cite of a same author. I solved this with a "foot"-tracker i found, but now i have a problem with the footcites-command, because a cite with `\footcites{A}{B}` and after that `\footcite{B}` causes "ibid" in the footnote after - without the foot-tracker-commands, the foot is ok, but the text not. I think, the following example will show my problem better.

```
\begin{filecontents}{lit.bib}
@misc{Book1, author = {Author, A.}, year = {2001}, title = {Alpha},}
@misc{Book2, author = {Buthor, B.}, year = {2002}, title = {Bravo},}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

 %own tracker i found on web
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@foot
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@foot
  \booltrue{citetracker}}
\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\def\blx@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
       {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}
\def\blx@ibidreset@foot{%
  \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
    {}
\makeatother

\usepackage[bibstyle=authoryear,citestyle=authoryear-icomp,backend=bibtex,ibidtracker=foot]{biblatex}
\bibliography{lit}

\begin{document}

All fine --- Cite one author \cite{Book1} 
and thats it\footcite{Book1}. Now \cite{Book1} again\footcite{Book1}.

Problem --- Here are two authors\footcites{Book2}{Book1} 
and now the problem with cite the last author of the footcite again\footcite{Book1}.
\end{document}
```

The foot-tracker i take from:
[ibidem only in the footnotes and not in the running text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223434/ibidem-only-in-the-footnotes-and-not-in-the-running-text)

Here is the actual output:
[image: Textbody]
[image: Footer]

Footnote 4 has to be "Author 2001".

P.S. My first question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you seem to want is the (`con`)`strict` behaviour of `biblatex`'s trackers where potentially ambiguous "ibid"s (especially those involving multiple citations) are suppressed. (See p. 56 of [the `biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf)).

Your initial definition of the `foot` tracker was based on the `context` tracker, we can now base it on `constrict`.
Because almost all commands will be identical with the original ones in `biblatex2.sty` our redefinition can be very short

```
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@constrict
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@constrict
  \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@ifcitesingle
       {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
          {\blx@ifmpfncheck
             {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@foot}
             {\@secondoftwo}}
          {\@secondoftwo}}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother
```

You see that we re-used the original `ibidtracker` and `ibidreset` commands and only changed `ifciteibid` a little bit.

MWE

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
  \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
  \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@constrict
  \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@constrict
  \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@ifcitesingle
       {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
          {\blx@ifmpfncheck
             {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@foot}
             {\@secondoftwo}}
          {\@secondoftwo}}
       {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
\makeatother

\usepackage[style=authortitle-icomp,backend=biber,ibidtracker=foot]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}

All fine --- Cite one author \cite{cicero} 
and thats it\footcite{cicero}. Now \cite{cicero} again\footcite{cicero}.

Problem --- Here are two authors\footcites{wilde}{cicero} 
and now the problem with cite the last author of the footcite again\footcite{cicero}.
\end{document}
```

[image]