# Problem with authoryear-icomp and ibidem in citation using BibLaTeX

Tags: biblatex, citing

I'm happily using BibLaTeX (3.4) with Biber (2.5).

With some tricks found on http://tex.stackexchange.com I've obtained exactly what I desire for my bibliography but I have a problem with footnote citations.

I would like this result:
[image]
but using the **same** command for the first and second footnote citations, in oder to avoid bothering about which is the first citation.

Note that I want the automatic “ibidem” only in footnotes (I found here: 
[ibidem only in the footnotes and not in the running text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/223434/ibidem-only-in-the-footnotes-and-not-in-the-running-text) how to do it) and I have some bib items with shortauthor.

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% package hyperref
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}

% ibidem only in footnotes
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
\let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
\let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@foot
\let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@foot
\booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
\ifbool{citetracker}
{\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
    {\@secondoftwo}}
{\@secondoftwo}}

 \def\blx@ibidtracker@foot{%
\ifbool{citetracker}
{\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
    {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}}
{}}

\def\blx@ibidreset@foot{%
\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
{\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
{}
\makeatother

% biblatex package
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, natbib=true, backend=biber, hyperref=true, ibidtracker=foot, pagetracker=page]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% CITATION
% no comma in author (year)
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% unified hyperlink on author (year) 
\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
\bibhyperref{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
\DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
\bibhyperref{%
    #1%
    \ifbool{cbx:parens}
    {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
    {}}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
\printtext[citehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{cite}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}}
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
\ifboolexpr{
    not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
    test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} 
}
{\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
{}%
\printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
    \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
    \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

% unified hyperlink on (author, year)
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\def\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
\printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}%
    \def\nameyeardelim{\addspace}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@article{item,
title={Title A},
author={AuthorA, NameA},
year={2015}
}
@manual{shortitem,
title={Title C},
author={{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}},
year={1988},
shortauthor = {BCBS}
}

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

First footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".\footnote{\citet{item} for first footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".} \\
Second footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".\footnote{\Cite{item} for second footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".} 

First footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".\footnote{\citet{shortitem} for first footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".} \\
Second footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".\footnote{\Cite{shortitem} for second footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".} \\
\end{document}
```

EDIT:

Trying to found a solution by myself, I've added this command (please don't laught):

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citet}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:init}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\ifciteibid{\usebibmacro{cite}}{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Now, if I use `\Citet` for all the citations of the original MWE, it works, but if I try to put the page number in a citation I get the error:

> ! Package biblatex Error: Unbalanced parentheses or
>   brackets.

See the new MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% package hyperref
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}

% ibidem only in footnotes
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
    \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
    \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@foot
    \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@foot
    \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
    \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
        {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
        {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@foot{%
    \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
        {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
        {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidreset@foot{%
    \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
{}
\makeatother

% biblatex package
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, natbib=true, backend=biber, hyperref=true, ibidtracker=foot, pagetracker=page]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% CITATION
% no comma in author (year)
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}

% unified hyperlink on author (year) 
\DeclareFieldFormat{citehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{textcitehyperref}{%
    \DeclareFieldAlias{bibhyperref}{noformat}% Avoid nested links
    \bibhyperref{%
        #1%
        \ifbool{cbx:parens}
        {\bibcloseparen\global\boolfalse{cbx:parens}}
        {}}}
\savebibmacro{cite}
\savebibmacro{textcite}
\renewbibmacro*{cite}{%
    \printtext[citehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{cite}%
        \usebibmacro{cite}}}
\renewbibmacro*{textcite}{%
    \ifboolexpr{
        not test {\iffieldundef{postnote}} and
        test {\ifnumequal{\value{citecount}}{\value{citetotal}}} 
    }
    {\DeclareFieldAlias{textcitehyperref}{noformat}}
    {}%
    \printtext[textcitehyperref]{%
        \restorebibmacro{textcite}%
        \usebibmacro{textcite}}}

% unified hyperlink on (author, year)
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\def\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \printtext[bibhyperref]{\usebibmacro{cite}%
        \def\nameyeardelim{\addspace}}}
{\multicitedelim}
{\usebibmacro{postnote}}

% My citet command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citet}
    {\usebibmacro{cite:init}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
    {\ifciteibid{\usebibmacro{cite}}{\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
    {\multicitedelim}
    {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @article{item,
        title={Title A},
        author={AuthorA, NameA},
        year={2015}
    }
        @manual{shortitem,
        title={Title C},
        author={{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}},
        year={1988},
        shortauthor = {BCBS}
    }

\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    First footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".\footnote{\Citet{item} for first footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".} \\
    Second footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".\footnote{\Citet{item} for second footnote citation when the bib item has only "author".} 

    First footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".\footnote{\Citet{shortitem} for first footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".} \\
    Second footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".\footnote{\Citet{shortitem} for second footnote citation when the bib item also has "shortauthor".} \\ 
    Error with \citet[11]{item}.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the end I've found the solution by myself.

I've deleted the code for the "unified hyperlinks" which was referred to `authoryear`, not to `authoryear-icomp`, and I've created my own `\citet` and `\citep` commands.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openright]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[british,english]{babel}
\usepackage{filecontents}

% package hyperref
\usepackage[unicode=true,pdfusetitle,
bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=false,bookmarksopen=false,
breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 1},backref=false,colorlinks=false]
{hyperref}

% ibidem only in footnotes
\makeatletter
\def\blx@opt@ibidtracker@foot{%
    \let\blx@imc@ifciteibid\blx@ifciteibid@foot
    \let\blx@ibidtracker\blx@ibidtracker@foot
    \let\blx@ibidreset\blx@ibidreset@foot
    \booltrue{citetracker}}

\def\blx@ifciteibid@foot{%
    \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
        {\blx@imc@iffieldequals{entrykey}\blx@lastkey@text}
        {\@secondoftwo}}
    {\@secondoftwo}}

\def\blx@ibidtracker@foot{%
    \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\iftoggle{blx@footnote}
        {\global\let\blx@lastkey@text\abx@field@entrykey}
        {\global\let\blx@lastkey@foot\abx@field@entrykey}}
    {}}

\def\blx@ibidreset@foot{%
    \iftoggle{blx@footnote}
    {\global\undef\blx@lastkey@text}}
{}
\makeatother

% biblatex package
\usepackage[style=authoryear-icomp, natbib=true, backend=biber, hyperref=true, ibidtracker=foot, pagetracker=page]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% CITATION
% no comma in author (year)
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addspace}
% semicolon as compcitedelim
\renewcommand{\compcitedelim}{;\addspace}

% my citet command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citet}
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
    \usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\ifciteibid%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{cite}}%
    {\usebibmacro{citeindex}\usebibmacro{textcite}}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{textcite:postnote}}

% my citep command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citep}[\mkbibparens]
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}\usebibmacro{prenote}}
{\def\nameyeardelim{\addcomma\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{citeindex}%
    \usebibmacro{cite}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

    @article{itemA,
        title={Title A},
        author={AuthorA, NameA},
        year={2015}
    }
    @article{itemB,
        title={Title B},
        author={AuthorA, NameA},
        year={2015}
    }
    @article{itemC,
        title={Title C},
        author={AuthorA, NameA},
        year={2016}
    }
        @manual{shortitemA,
        title={Title A},
        author={{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}},
        year={1988},
        shortauthor = {BCBS}
    }
     @manual{shortitemB,
        title={Title B},
        author={{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}},
        year={1988},
        shortauthor = {BCBS}
     } 
     @manual{shortitemC,
        title={Title C},
        author={{Basel Committee on Banking Supervision}},
        year={2006},
        shortauthor = {BCBS}
        }
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

    Now footnotes work as I like:\\

    Author: first\footnote{\Citet{itemA} first footnote citation} and second\footnote{\Citet{itemA} second footnote citation} footnote\\
    Shortauthor: first\footnote{\Citet{shortitemA} first footnote citation} and second\footnote{\Citet{shortitemA} second footnote citation} footnote\\

        And also all the rest works:\\

    With author:\\

    \verb|\citet| normal: \citet{itemA} \\
    \verb|\citet| with page: \citet[1]{itemA}\\
    \verb|\citet| multicite: \citet{itemA, itemB, itemC}    \\

    \verb|\citep| normal: \citep{itemA}\\
    \verb|\citep| with page: \citep[1]{itemA}\\
    \verb|\citep| multicite: \citep{itemA, itemB, itemC}\\

    With shortauthor:\\

    \verb|\citet| normal: \citet{shortitemA} \\
    \verb|\citet| with page: \citet[1]{shortitemA}\\
    \verb|\citet| multicite: \citet{shortitemA, shortitemB, shortitemC}\\

    \verb|\citep| normal: \citep{shortitemA}\\
    \verb|\citep| with page: \citep[1]{shortitemA}\\
    \verb|\citep| multicite: \citep{shortitemA, shortitemB, shortitemC}

    \newpage

    Also footnotes with \verb|\citep| works as I like:\\

    Author: first\footnote{First footnote citation \citep{itemA} } and second\footnote{Second footnote citation \citep{itemA}} footnote\\
    Shortauthor: first\footnote{First footnote citation \Citep{shortitemA}} and second\footnote{Second footnote citation \citep{shortitemA}} footnote       

\end{document}
```